# What causes the sugar to turn grainy after I have cooked it for a glaze or cooking it with butter for carmelizing?

Tags: sugar, melting-sugar

I tried several times to cook the glaze for a strawberry glaze pie and the sugar, water, and cornstarch would thicken but then the sugar would turn grainy.  I have also tried to boil water, sugar, and butter to make a carmel type sauce to pour over corn curls and it thickens and seems to be fine but then turns grainy right after I take it off the stove.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your syrups are crystallizing on you.

For a smooth glaze or caramel, you want tiny little sugar crystals. When you heat your sugar and water mixture, after a certain temperature the water becomes super-saturated with the sugar.

After this super-saturation point, things get dicey. If the solution is disturbed--say by stirring, or an undissolved sugar crystal or other foreign particle getting into the solution--the sugar can rapidly come out of solution and form big crystals. This could be why your confections are grainy.

There are a lot of resources online that have the science behind it and suggestions on preventing it ([example](http://www.ochef.com/80.htm), [example](http://cookingsciencetradition.blogspot.com/2010/12/crystallization-of-sugar.html), [example](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/dailydish/2011/10/test-kitchen-tips-keeping-cooked-sugar-from-crystalizing.html)). To summarize a few:

- Always use a clean pot or pan.
- Make sure the sugar is completely dissolved before it comes to a boil
- Dip a pastry brush in water to wash away any sugar that sticks to the side of the pot or pan as the sugar heats.
- Combine the sugar with a little water (it should have the consistency of wet sand) before cooking.
- Avoid stirring the sugar when it comes to a simmer.
- Cover the pan loosely with a lid or baking sheet.
- Add a little acid (such as a touch of lemon juice) or corn syrup to the sugar-water mixture before cooking

Comment: I second the corn syrup tip. It can be a life saver when doing any work with sugar syrups.

Comment: I've not heard of using acid in sugar work. I'm guessing it breaks some of the glucose into sucrose and fructose.

Comment: I've been doing some candy work for Christmas, and both recipes I used called for acid (cream of tarter). So my guess was correct.

Answer (score -1):

When you add milk to the cooked brown sugar and butter mixture, add SLOWLY while stirring constantly. Adding cold milk too suddenly causes the sugar to crystallize. A simple solution. This is what works for me always!